# Creating more than one root type with generative type provider

Tags: f#, type-providers

Generative type providers seem to have an issue with having more than one root type.
Complete repro is available here: https://gist.github.com/dsevastianov/46d1a8495c4af46a9875. Following example

```
#r @"SampleProvider.dll"
type Birch = Sample.Sample<"birch">
type Elm = Sample.Sample<"elm">

let birch = Birch.birch()
let elm = Elm.elm()
elm.Branches <- ([|Elm.elm()|])
```

fails at compile time (not at design time):

```
FSC: error FS2014: A problem occurred writing the binary 'obj\Debug\Tests.dll': 
Error in pass3 for type Schema, error: Error in GetMethodRefAsMethodDefIdx for 
mref = (".ctor", "ZipLookup"), error: Exception of type Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILBinaryWriter+MethodDefNotFound' was thrown.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that it is necessary to create separate temp assembly for each root type. I amended Gist to reflect the solution:  https://gist.github.com/dsevastianov/46d1a8495c4af46a9875